# Accessing Class member variables from prototype functions in call-back in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, this, javascript-objects, dom-events

I have the following code:

```
function MyClass(udpSocket)
{
  this.IPSocket = udpSocket;
  this.port;
  this.DestAddr;
}

MyClass.prototype.handleMessage = function(message)
{

 var msg = JSON.parse(message);

    switch(msg.type) 
    {
        case "Send":
        var BufToSend = "Hey";
        this.IPSocket.send(BufToSend, 0, BufToSend.length, this.port, this.DestAddr, function(err, bytes) 
        {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
    break;

MyClass.prototype.setWebSocketConnection = function( ws)
{
    this.wsConnection = ws;


    this.wsConnection.on('message', function incoming(message) 
    {
        MyClass.prototype.handleMessage( message );
    });
}

MyClass.prototype.setUdpPort = function( PORT )
{
    this.port = PORT;
}

MyClass.prototype.setDestAddr = function( DEST_ADDR )
{
    this.DestAddr = DEST_ADDR;
}

exports.mMyClass = MyClass;
```

The problem is when I enter the callback handleMessage I have no access to the Myclass member variables and therefor am unable to send a message out over therefor udpSocket.
Any Ideas?

Comment: I guess you're looking for [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Can you add a comment in the code where you think there is a problem! I just took a glance at it and there seems nothing wrong in `handleMessage`. The only error I've noticed is in `setWebSocketConnection`!

Comment: When i call this.IPSocket.send i get; Cannot read property of 'send' undefined

Answer (score 0):

If you save a pointer to `this` you can reference it inside a callback function. Here's a simple example:

```js
var MyClass = function(prop) {
  this.prop = prop;
};

MyClass.prototype.printProp = function() {
  
  var innerFunction = function(callback) {
    callback();
  };
  
  innerFunction(function() {
    console.log('without the referece to the correct "this": ', this.prop);
  });
  
  var that = this;
  innerFunction(function() {
    console.log('with the referece: ', that.prop);
  });
  
};

var instance = new MyClass('hi there');

instance.printProp();
```